# Allows users to pass from flat to threaded view for forum comments

Tags: 7, views, comments

We've migrated a site from Drupal 5 to Drupal 7, and we were unable to figure out how to allow user to change between flat and threaded view for the forum comments. This was possible in Drupal 5, but in Drupal 7 it's only possible to change the default display mode per content type (as an administrator option).

Is there a way to allow this for the users?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on Drupal 7 that setting is not per user, but per content type. So you need to go to the content type's comment settings and choose either flat or threaded view.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any plugin to change that? Or I have to dive into the code to change it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no module that reverts comments settings for Drupal 7 which existed on Drupal 5, so I am afraid you have to dive into coding.